# What (semi-)official hitchhiking spots exist in The Netherlands?

Tags: hitchhiking, netherlands

In relation to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/are-there-countries-other-than-the-netherlands-that-support-hitchhiking), what official hitchhiking spots exist in The Netherlands? Is there more than one such sign in The Netherlands, besides the one pictured at Gooiseweg (Amsterdam) in the other question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those spots are called 'Liftershalte' in Dutch, Wikipedia has a list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liftershalte Don't expect too much there are only 6 of those, it's a bit of a gimmick more then anything else.